# What are the best interface features of a CMS you have used?

Tags: user-interface, content-management-system

There are a million and one CMS' that do a good job but the interface and usability of it let the entire system down (like a lot of websites out there).

Whenever I need to develop a bespoke system for content management I always try and draw on my past experiences and those of my clients to work out what works well and what doesn't. So each time I do one there is a similarity to the last but with some extra tweaking to make it that much better.

**So the question is what CMS interface / features have you found a pleasure to work with and why?**

Note: This could be editing pages, products, sitemaps, just about anything you needed to manage through a CMS

Answer (score 2):

I personally think inline-editing is a massive speed boost for clients and developers.

Comment: That rather depends on a) having a very good editor b) having untrained editors. I've seen WYSIWYG tools generate invalid markup and be quite inflexible, even if you know a trivial amount of HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 6's draggable menu reordering is a great feature. It is faster and more intuitive than the weight system from Drupal 5 and the up/down arrows I have seen elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with jchrista, drag-and-drop is very nice.  This is the feature that initially drew me to Sitefinity.  There is an online demo of this [here](http://demo.sitefinity.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I hate InterWoven (just because I find it slow and non intuitive--subjective..), but it has a nice WorkFlow setting that enables you to control the versions you have on the server between what you have been working on and what should be deployed.

Also a good (go back to before the screw up) productivity tools

MOSS has lots of interesting features that are supposed to do the same thing also, which I will look forward to test as we move towards that platform.